# Regarding OSTs in "Your Lie in April" anime

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

Can someone tell me the names of all the songs in *Your Lie in April* anime? Only the songs like the opening, ending, and background songs, not the piano pieces.

Comment: What is insufficient on [this](http://shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso.wikia.com/wiki/Music)?

Answer (score 4):

Here's the VGMdb page for the soundtrack album: http://vgmdb.net/album/49046. Knock yourself out. If you happen to want the piano pieces, I believe all of them are on this album: http://vgmdb.net/album/47707.

[The wikia](http://shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso.wikia.com/wiki/Music) that @Zereges linked in [this comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43085/regarding-osts-in-your-lie-in-april-anime#comment57822_43085) appears to contain much the same information, if you prefer that.